# Android ListView set two different adapter. ListView is not updated to newly set adapter until I scroll it

Tags: android, listview, listview-adapter

I have 2 different adapter for a `ListView`. Both adapters extends `BaseAdapter`.
I have 2 Button in the header view of the `ListView`.

Button 1 call `ListView.setAdapter(adapter1);`
Button 2 call `ListView.setAdapter(adapter2);`

The first time I click either one of the button. The `ListView` update to another adapter view immediately.

However, the second time I click either one of the button. The Button listener will not trigger until I scroll the `ListView`.

I have tried to put a toast inside the button listener. The toast is only called after I scroll the `ListView`.

Anyone have any idea what is the problem?

Comment: You need to show more code.

Answer (score 0):

The UI in Android is efficient and will only update when it NEEDS to.  In the case of your list the UI only updates when you scroll it because it needs to fetch more items for the list.  To force an update you need to call `invalidate()` on your `ListView`.

Comment: i tried to call invalidate(), notifyDataSetChanged() and refreshDrawableState(). All of these are not working. I think the problem is on the Button onClickListener. It is only triggered after i scroll the view